# Function selection_column(60,84) PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```sql
RAISE NOTICE ' Hello everyone !'
```

I have a technical question for the group. I'm looking to find out if it's possible to create a function that selects columns based on their position in a table. For instance, I'd like to be able to execute a query like this:

```sql
SELECT FUNCTION(21, 65) FROM table;
```

Result:

| column 21 | column 22 | .... | column 65 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 val 21 | row 1 val 22 | .... | row 1 val 65 |
| row 2 val 21 | row 2 val 22 | .... | row 2 val 65 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| row N val 21 | row N val 22 | .... | row N val 65 |

I'm using a plpgsql function, but I find it cumbersome because it requires specifying the schema and table, as well as the column indices, like this: `col('schema', 'table', 21, 65)`, to retrieve the list of columns.
I'd appreciate any suggestions or insights you might have on this topic. Thanks in advance!

I am looking for a function integrated into PostgreSQL or another more suitable method.

Comment: Output structure (resulting fields and types) must be known at call time, so no, or only indirectly. You can create a routine that does that but doesn't return the result directly to the caller, but instead dumps the result to a table and returns its name. What are you trying to achieve, what's it for? If you keep a single `array` or `jsonb`-type column, they both support slices, but resulting denormalised table comes with other problems.

Comment: From what I understand, you're looking for a function that returns a *varying* number of columns of *varying* types, depending on function parameters and the source table.

Comment: To get a list of column names between column 21 and 65, you can get that from [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) where each column of each table is marked with `ordinal_position`. If that's all you want, it's right there. If you want a function that returns a table consisting of those columns, you'll need the function with a two-step call and indirect response.

Comment: Slightly offtopic: Rather unusual query since your data model should not be dependent on the position of a column in the table. The data types can also be a challenge. I would take a second look at the current data model and fix the real issues.

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek for your insights. I have tables modified with new columns and need fast field access. Columns were added haphazardly, and Python imports cause compliance issues. This function will help our team collaborate effectively on the same table areas, ensuring smooth operation of linked applications.

Comment: "Columns were added haphazardly"... that seems even more reason to not work this way....